# upcasting to interface with private inheritance

Tags: c++, upcasting, private-inheritance

I have the following situation

```cpp
class Interface {
};

class ComplicatedObject : public Interface {
};
```

and I would like to give a simplified version of the ComplicatedObject, still providing the Interface. I was thinking to private inheritance, such as

```cpp
class Simplified : private ComplicatedObject {
};
```

but, of course, I can't easily upcast to Interface like

```cpp
int main() {
  Interface* p = new Simplified();
}
```

Is composition the only way to go? or is there some workaround? like implicit conversion

Comment: What objective are you trying to achieve by providing a simplified interface? Is there a problem this is intended to solve?

Comment: If `Simplified` also fully implements `Interface` it could inherit from it, but you would need virtual inheritance.

Comment: It won't work here since you have an owning pointer, but consider an implicit conversion operator to convert from `Interface &` to `Simplified &`.

Comment: Can you use a public static method that does the new and then upcasts on return?

Comment: You might be able to swap the inheritance: Complicated derives from Simplified, which derives from Interface.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm my complicated object wraps an external library object that makes a lot of stuff that I don't want to show for a particular case of Simplified

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm can't swap

Comment: Why do you want to avoid composition? "`Simplified` inherits `Interface` and holds a `ComplicatedObject` that it defers to" seems uncomplicated to me.

Comment: @molbdnilo just being lazy but yep, I know that composition is possible

Answer (score 1):

> Is composition the only way to go?

Upcasting won't work with composition either. Private inheritance is effectively composition from the perspective of outside the class.

> or is there some workaround?

Not implicit, but you could provide a set of member functions that return a reference to the base.

---

A more radical change - but more sensible - is to change the premise and use virtual inheritance:

```
class Interface {};

class ComplicatedObject : public virtual Interface {};

class Simplified : private ComplicatedObject, public virtual Interface {};
```

This can be done without virutal inhertance as well, but in that case you would need to re-implement all virtual functions and delegate to the private base explicitly.

Comment: I think I will go with composition; the actual case is more complicated than this and virual inheritance should be propagated all the way up the actual inheritance tree.